# How to register singleton factory resolving scoped objects in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

When I'm registering factory for IPersonProvider like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IPersonProvider, PersonProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<Func<IPersonProvider>>(sp => () => sp.GetService<IPersonProvider>());
```

I'm getting error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'DependencyApp.Provider.IPersonProvider' from root provider.

I'm aware that I can't resolve Singleton object with Scoped dependencies, but as I understand my factory doesn't have any Scoped dependencies - in fact it doesn't have any dependencies. It just creates objects when I ask to like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly Func<IPersonProvider> _factory;

    public HomeController(Func<IPersonProvider> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Route("/")]
    public string Calculate()
    {
        var personProvider = _factory();
        //.
        //.
        //.

        return "test";
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error then? How to solve the problem? I believe registering factory as Singleton that can live as long as the whole application shouldn't have any problem creating scoped objects - eventually those created objects aren't really dependencies of the singleton.

Comment: Is it still an issue if you make your `Func` to be a transient service?  The problem may be that since it's a singleton, the `sp` instance is the root instance, always, which may not be the case if you define the service as transient instead.

Comment: It works, It also works when I keep Func Singleton but make IPersonProvider transient. But I wonder why cant i keep Func Singleton and provider Scoped? Func is just creating objects, nothing more so I believe i should create it once per app.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you are having this issue is due to the instance of `IServiceProvider` being used.  When you register a service as singleton, then the root `IServiceProvider` is passed to the factory method.

So when you have:

```
services.AddSingleton<Func<IPersonProvider>>(sp => () => sp.GetService<IPersonProvider>());
```

It means that `sp` must be compatible with the singleton lifetime, which is only the root service provider.

To illustrate what I mean.

```
using (var scopedServiceProvider = sp.CreateScope())
{
    scopedServiceProvider.GetService<IPersonProvider>(); // valid

    sp.GetService<IPersonProvider>(); // not valid
}
```

However, when your factory method is of transient lifetime, the `sp` passed in no longer uses the root service provider and instead uses a derived one where the restriction of instantiating scoped services does not apply.

To reiterate the problem, the `sp` that you're using is not able to create scoped services, so it's not a matter of the service being returned being a `Func`, but instead the fact that the provider is the root one.

Answer (score -1):

I've done following its working fine:

```
 services.AddSingleton<ITokenManager, TokenManger>();
 services.AddScoped<ITokenProvider, TokenProvider>();

public class TokenProvider : ITokenProvider
{
    private readonly ITokenManager _tokenManager;
    public TokenProvider(ITokenManager tokenManager)
    {
        _tokenManager = tokenManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants the opposite of this.